# How to pass c++ template class to constructor when template arguments are not known?

Tags: c++, templates

Sorry if this is a double post. I'm almost sure this has been asked multiple times, but I'm unable to find it.

I mainly have a Java background. I haven't used C++ for a long time but I currently need to use it for microcontroller programming. In my main method, I have a display object for drawing to an e-paper display. I'd like to pass this object to a separate class that performs some drawing operations with it, but I'm struggling a little with this.

The display class is templated and gets initialized in the main method.

```
GxEPD2_BW<GxEPD2_154_D67, GxEPD2_154_D67::HEIGHT> display(GxEPD2_154_D67(SS, 17, 16, 4));
```

Now, my drawing class "Graph" has a constructor where `display` is passed as a parameter:

```
class Graph {

    public:
        Graph(GxEPD2_BW *display);
        ...
```

That's not working as C++ is complaining about the missing argument list of the templated class `GxEPD2_BW`.

The problem now is, I don't know what arguments to provide here. The template arguments `GxEPD2_154_D67` and `GxEPD2_154_D67::HEIGHT` define the specific display in use and I don't want my drawing class to rely on a specific display. It's supposed to take any kind of display class, no matter the parameterization, and work with it.

In Java, I would build the constructor like this:

```
public class Graph {

    public Graph(GxEPD2_BW<?, ?> display) {
        ...
```

and henceforth, I could pass any display implementation to it without worrying about the underlying display characteristics.

How would I go about this in C++? Or am I forcing something upon C++ that it's not supposed to do?

Comment: Firstly I would check if `GxEPD2_BW` has a non-template base class that you could pass a reference/pointer to. If not, the whole constructor needs to be a template: `template <??? A, ??? B> Graph(GxEPD2_BW<A, B> *display)` (look at the definition of `GxEPD2_BW` to know what to put in place of `???`).

Comment: c++ templates and java generics are very different concepts. Java generics are based on type erasure. C++ templates can be used for type erasure, but first and foremost they are about instantiating concrete types.

Comment: I think it's necessary to stipulate, especially for beginners learning C++, that there is no such things as "template classes" or "template functions". Instead, there are "class templates" and "function templates". This is important, because then you can imagine a _template_ as being a stencil or a rubber stamp that will stamp out the actual class or the actual function once instantiated.

Comment: To quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template): _"A class template by itself is not a type, or an object, or any other entity. No code is generated from a source file that contains only template definitions. In order for any code to appear, a template must be instantiated: the template arguments must be provided so that the compiler can generate an actual class (or function, from a function template)."_

Comment: Declaration of a generic class needs all compile time parameters in `template` keyword. For functions you can use the traditional `template` keyword, or the newer `auto` argument types or a mix of both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of a simpler example consider this template and a class that expects an instance as parameter to the constructor:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {};

struct Bar {
    Bar(Foo<??> ) {}    // pseduo code. Doesn't work like this!
};
```

First you need to understand that C++ templates are nothing like Java generics. Java generics are based on type erasure. Thats what allows you to have a `GxEPD2_BW<?, ?> display`. C++ templates are not based on type erasure. `Foo<int>` and `Foo<double>` are two completely different types. They have nothing in common (other than being instantiations of the same class template). C++ templates can be used for type erasure, but they don't do it out of the box. In C++ there is no type `Foo<?>` that would be the equivalent to the generic in Java.

Basically you have two choices. You can introduce a common base class, such that `Foo<int>` and `Foo<double>` do have a common base:

```
struct Base {};

template <typename T>
struct Foo : Base {};

struct Bar {
    Bar(std::unique_ptr<Base> b) {}
};
```

For runtime polymorphism you need pointers or references.

Alternatively you can consider to make `Bar` itself a template:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {};

template <typename T>
struct Bar {
    Bar(Foo<T> f) {}
};
```

Here, again, `Bar<int>` and `Bar<double>` are two completely different types, that have nothing in common (other than being instantiations of the same class template). And each has a concrete type (not a template) as argument for the constructor.

There are more variants and different ways. For example you could have a non-template `Bar` and only its constructor is a template. However, the two above are what I would consider the most straightforward ways.

Comment: Thanks for this thorough explanation. If I understand correctly: The first example would mean actually modifying the display class template's inheritance structure? And the second example means shifting the need to provide template parameters up a level, so I provide them in my main method where I also initialize the display template with it's parameters?

Comment: @user3792852 yes. More or less, thats it. Do you need a `Bar` constructed from a `Foo<A>` to be the same type as a `Bar` constructed from a `Foo<B>` is one question you need to answer for yourself. If yes, go for the first, if no, you can make `Bar` itself a class template

Comment: @user3792852 I mean, there is much more and the answer barely scratched the surface, but with those two alternatives you can go already a long way

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up what I decided to do.

I'm accepting the answer by 463035818_is_not_an_ai anyway as it gives a broader overview of the possibilities and an explanation of the problem.

The header file of my Graph class:

```
template <typename TYPE_CL, const uint16_t page_height> 
class Graph {

    public:
        Graph(GxEPD2_BW<TYPE_CL, page_height> *display);

    private:
        GxEPD2_BW<TYPE_CL, page_height>* display;
```

The implementation:

```
#include "Graph.h"

template <typename TYPE_CL, const uint16_t page_height> 
Graph<TYPE_CL, page_height>::Graph(GxEPD2_BW<TYPE_CL, page_height>* display) {
    this->display = display;
    this->display.displayMethod() //Work with the display...
}
```

And in the main method of the application:

```
#include "Graph.h"

// Initialize the display
GxEPD2_BW<GxEPD2_154_D67, GxEPD2_154_D67::HEIGHT> display(GxEPD2_154_D67(SS, 17, 16, 4));

// Create a new Graph object, providing the same template parameters 
// that went into the display initialization
Graph<GxEPD2_154_D67, GxEPD2_154_D67::HEIGHT> g();
```